# How do I compile a cpp file for chip ATtiny85

Tags: c++, atmel

I need to put a `.cpp` file on an [ATtiny85](http://www.atmel.com/devices/ATTINY85.aspx) chip. I'm not sure, but I think that I need to compile it in Atmel Studio 6, which has a compiler for that. I don't know how to do that. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Just start the IDE, click on menu *File* -> *New* -> *Project...*, select *GCC C++ Executable Project*, give a name and click *OK*. Select *ATtiny85* from the list, click *OK*, and the project is ready to start.

Then, you just need to write the code, put your code inside or replace the file. When it's ready, click on build/build project and it will compile it for you.

It's just like a C++ IDE. It's based on Microsoft [Visual Studio](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio).

If you want to burn the microcontroller too, you can setup an external tool at menu *Tools* -> *External tools...*. And if the chip is not in a board with something like an [ISP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/In-system_programming) interface, you will need a programmer.

Comment: OK, I have finished code. I just need to put it on the chip. What to do after I compile it?

Comment: You need an ISP programmer or something able to flash it. I'm using an Arduino to do it. If you have an Arduino, check this thread: [link]http://arduino.cc/forum/index.php/topic,65099.msg475663.html#msg475663 If you don't, you need to buy something like this: [link]http://dx.com/p/usb-avr-isp-avrisp-programmer-151161?item=3  Are this your first steps with microcontrollers? If so, you should start with something like Arduino, which has his own ISP interface and can be programmed easily by USB. Then you can use it as ISP for other Atmel MCUs when you are skilled.

Comment: Take a look to this video: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3joqP07Qo-g